# Reformat Javascript Object for use with Foreach

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, serialization

I have a form which has a repeatable field group. I am using `serializeArray()` on the form submit to get all of the form values however the repeatable fields aren't in an easily workable format so I need to modify these so I am able to utilise them within a foreach

This is the response from the `serializeArray()`

```
{
  "_acffr_repeatable_group_fields": "[\"acrepeater-vehical[0][vehicle-make]\",\"acrepeater-vehical[0][vehicle-model]\",null,\"acrepeater-vehical[0][vehicle-year]\",\"acrepeater-vehical[1][vehicle-make]\",\"acrepeater-vehical[1][vehicle-model]\",null,\"acrepeater-vehical[1][vehicle-year]\",\"acrepeater-vehical[2][vehicle-make]\",\"acrepeater-vehical[2][vehicle-model]\",null,\"acrepeater-vehical[2][vehicle-year]\"]",
  "_acffr_repeatable_groups": "[\"acrepeater-vehical\"]",
  "your-name": "Name",
  "your-email": "test@test.com",
  "YourZipCode": "zip code",
  "acrepeater-vehical[0][vehicle-make]": "Make 1",
  "acrepeater-vehical[0][vehicle-model]": "Model 1",
  "acrepeater-vehical[0][vehicle-type]": "Car",
  "acrepeater-vehical[0][vehicle-year]": "2001",
  "acrepeater-vehical[1][vehicle-make]": "Make 2",
  "acrepeater-vehical[1][vehicle-model]": "Model 2",
  "acrepeater-vehical[1][vehicle-type]": "Truck",
  "acrepeater-vehical[1][vehicle-year]": "2002",
  "acrepeater-vehical[2][vehicle-make]": "Make 3",
  "acrepeater-vehical[2][vehicle-model]": "Model 3",
  "acrepeater-vehical[2][vehicle-type]": "Commercial",
  "acrepeater-vehical[2][vehicle-year]": "2003"
}
```

As you can see from the above, for each repeated group of fields it adds the [N] to the acpeater-vehical however this flat format doesn't permit me to loop through the fieldsets

How could I reformat this to be in the appropriate format?

Comment: What is the "appropriate format"? Please provide expected output.

Comment: One possibility: `<form>.querySelectorAll('[name^="acrepeater-vehical"]')` and on each iteration use a regex or something to check which item you're on, but that seems a bit too ugly. There should be a more elegant way!

Comment: I assume you're looking for an array of objects, where the objects have properties like `vehicle-make` and so on?

Comment: Looks like https://github.com/marioizquierdo/jquery.serializeJSON is an option

Comment: @Snow yes that is correct. Sorry, should have added an example format of what is required to my question. I essentially need an array of vehicals with the sub fields

Comment: @Snow that looks promising, I will give it a try, thank you!